# Service variable or Service Observable or Service Subject?

Tags: angular, rxjs, subject

I’ve been pondering on the global declaration of variables and I’ve been unable to understand why someone would use a Subject in a service when a variable could do the same job or an Observable for that matter. Please clarify my doubts

Answer (score 2):

I think you to better understand why Subject is a better choice than Observables is it understand their differences

Observables are unicast => *(each subscribed Observer owns an independent execution of the Observable),*

While Subjects are multicast.
Another example would is that if we console.log(random function) in an observable, it will show different results.
While if we did the same with Subject, the same value will be displayed.

With an Observable you can't fetch the previous values. With Subject you can fetch previous values if you use a slightly different version of Subject i.e. ReplaySubject.

This helps in getting data that was fetched before your component was initialized.

Comment: I guess Subjects would make more sense with an API call, because in the case whereby I need to add to cart, I could just create a variable in the service and have my components make use of that. Correct me if I’m wrong